# mating prevention as Tza'ar Ba'alei Chayim

Tags: animals, sexuality, tzaar-baalei-chayyim

Does anyone know whether keeping an animal of one sex as a pet is considered Tza'ar Ba'alei Chayim or not, since it cannot mate?

Comment: Humanbeing, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for your interesting question (and, elsewhere, your answer). Please consider [registering](http://mi.yodeya.com/users/login) your [account](http://mi.yodeya.com/users/1477), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 2):

Tza'ar ba'alei chayim concerns practices that physically or (perhaps) psychologically hurt the animal.  Aside from the possible case of a female animal in heat, not mating does not appear to cause distress to animals.  Anecdotally, [Judaism 101](http://www.jewfaq.org/animals.htm) reports a story of an Orthodox pet owner giving a pet birth-control pills and asserts that this would not be a violation of halacha.

The absence of evidence is not itself necessarily evidence, but I have never heard of anybody with a single pet being required to get another or give up that pet, and I know lots of Jews who have one cat or dog.

Comment: +1. Any source for "...not mating does not appear to cause distress to animals"?

Comment: @msh210, just observation from friends who take in not-necessarily-altered animals, but I'll be talking with my vet later today anyway, so bli neder I'll try to ask for something concrete.  *Physically* there doesn't seem to be any damage; how much emotional/psycholigical impact (1) is present and (2) we need to consider is harder to know.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, I'm not sure, but sending away the mother bird and not slaughtering a cow and her calf on the same day would seem to be in this space.  There's no physical reason for either.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Mitzvot can have many reasons.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin They get silenced for _praying_ with it. I think it's because using it like that in prayer implies it is the only reason. Monica's diyuk does not exclude the existence of another reason, only another physical one.